# How to set level of newly placed FamilyInstance?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm placing a new face-based family instance into my Revit model with the help of the `NewFamilyInstance Method (Face, XYZ, XYZ, FamilySymbol)`  method described [here](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/3afcdf82-b25c-3092-d42c-b60490075d22.htm). This works fine, except the instance does not have its level set to that of the host (it's set to -1 when accessed through the API and just left blank in the UI).

I tried setting the level like such

```
placedInstance.LevelId = hostWall.LevelId
```

and following [this approach](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/01/family-instance-missing-level-property.html) also tried

```
placedInstance.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.FAMILY_LEVEL_PARAM).Set(hostWall.LevelId);
```

but both throw an error saying the parameter is readonly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

On some elements, the element level can only be set during the creation of the element. For that, I would assume that you need to use a different [overload of the `NewFamilyInstance` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/0c0d640b-7810-55e4-3c5e-cd295dede87b.htm). Please refer to this explanation by The Building Coder and a few recent discussions of related topics in the Revit API discussion forum:

- [Change level of existing element](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/06/creating-material-texture-and-retaining-pixels.html#4)
- [LevelId is null](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/levelid-is-null/m-p/11392692)
- [Change level on line based family](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/change-level-on-line-based-family/m-p/10307454)

Comment: That is unfortunate. Does that mean I'd have to try out the overloads one by one and hope that one of the methods sets the level for me?

Comment: There are some ways to limit the number of possible options. Here are some old examples from 2011 of several such explorations: https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/01/newfamilyinstance-overloads.html